# Use a Subdomain with Nginx to get a JSON from an Endpoint

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, digital-ocean

I currently have a deployed application. https://dostoevsky.rest/

It works well with Nginx and Docker.

However, I want to get a JSON when I hit the endpoint https://dostoevsky.rest/api/rand with a subdomain.

So, I want the subdomain **api.dostoevsky.rest** to redirect https://dostoevsky.rest/api/rand.

I thought I could configure Nginx as a reverse proxy, so I did the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name api.dostoevsky.rest www.api.dostoevsky.rest;

    root /var/www/api.dostoevsky.rest/html;

    location / {
           proxy_pass http://<IP>;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       }

    location /api/rand {
        proxy_pass http://<IP>/api/rand;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

However, when I do `curl api.dostoevsky.rest` I get the message:

```
<html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.21.3</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm assuming the resource isn't found?

However, if I do `curl https://dostoevsky.rest/api/rand` it works fine. So, I think I'm making a mistake with the reverse proxy. Any help would be appreciated. Sorry if this is a low-quality question; I'm new to using Nginx.

Deployed on a DigitalOcean droplet.

Following is my complete `nginx.conf` file:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name dostoevsky.rest www.dostoevsky.rest;

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
          allow all;
          root /var/www/html;
        }

        location / {
                rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name dostoevsky.rest www.dostoevsky.rest;

        server_tokens off;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dostoevsky.rest/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dostoevsky.rest/privkey.pem;

        ssl_buffer_size 8k;

        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

        ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
        ssl_session_tickets off;

        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        resolver 8.8.8.8;

        location / {
                try_files $uri @nodejs;
        }

        location @nodejs {
                proxy_pass http://nodejs:8080;
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
                add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
                add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
                add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
                add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
                # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
                # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications
        }

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name api.dostoevsky.rest www.api.dostoevsky.rest;

    root /var/www/api.dostoevsky.rest/html;

    location / {
           proxy_pass http://<IP>;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       }

    location /api/rand {
        proxy_pass http://<IP>/api/rand;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your DNS. To use a subdomain, you first need DNS to point `api.dostoevsky.rest` to your IP address. This can be a wildcard entry for `dostoevsky.rest` or a specific record for `api.dostoevsky.rest`.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thank you for the response. I added it to the DNS records. However, I seem to be getting a timeout error: 504 Gateway Time-out. Could it be it's not finding the resource?